# Launch process with limited capabilities on minimal Busybox-based system

Tags: linux, shell, busybox, capabilities

In a minimal Busybox-based Linux system with access to the root user, how can one launch a process with a **specific limited set of Linux [capabilities(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)** without requiring any tools beyond busybox?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know both of these things. What I what is to ensure a process that can have *exactly* a specific list of capabilities. The contents of this list is configurable.

Comment: What applets are enabled in your build of busybox? Is `setfattr` one of them?

Comment: Nevermind, busybox' setfattr doesn't seem to support passing values hex or base64 encoded so is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

So, up front, this does require some [`libcap`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/) tools built from sources in a non-default way - so I admit it isn't the answer you were hoping for (just busybox)... However, the binaries are small and here is a way to explore:

The `libcap` distribution has a sub-directory that uses busybox to test against built-from-source kernels. I've used it to triage a few kernel bugs and fixes/features for `libcap` over the years. You can explore it here:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/kdebug

One of the things that does is run the [`quicktest.sh`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/progs/quicktest.sh) `libcap` compatibility test suite at start up inside a busybox target. It assumes you have some kernel sources at this relative location `kdebug/../../linux/` in order to build the system to test. The basic idea is you untar/git clone the `libcap` sources and do this:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git
$ cd libcap/kdebug
$ make
```

The first time you try this, it will likely fail to build because it has a whole bunch of dependencies, `qemu` etc. to launch this busybox target (enumerating those should really be explained in a README). But the binaries once inside the `busybox` setup are pretty minimal.

If you can get the above to work, with this command line you can also interact with the `qemu` hosted system after the tests have completed:

```
$ make shell
```

[exit and Ctrl-d will both exit qemu].

If you are trying to do something subtle, `quicktest.sh` has a lot of examples demonstrating how to use the custom built `./capsh` and `./setcap` etc binaries to run things with privilege inside a busbox based system. Built from sources, if you have a static `glibc` on your host system to link against, `capsh` and `setcap` are both fully static binaries.

All that being said, within that system, you can do something like:

```
# ./capsh --iab="^cap_net_raw" --secbits=15 == --print
Current: cap_net_raw=eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
Ambient set =cap_net_raw
Current IAB: ^cap_net_raw
Securebits: 017/0xf/4'b1111 (no-new-privs=0)
 secure-noroot: yes (locked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: yes (locked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root) euid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

Which demonstrates how to place limits on `root` privileges to the single `cap_net_raw` capability. For whatever task you want to run you have two choices:

- put some file capabilities on a binary and change user (from root) to run it:

```
# ./setcap cap_net_raw=ep ./yourbinary
# ./capsh --user=nobody -- -c "./yourbinary"
```

- or use the above `capsh` mechanism to drop `root` privilege and use ambient capabilities to limit a privileged `nobody` user while running your program:

```
# ./capsh --user=nobody --iab="^cap_net_raw" -- -c "./yourbinary"
```